# Overlayed scrollbar obscures important sidebar buttons (Ubuntu 22.04/LibreOffice 7.3.7.2.)

Tags: 22.04, libreoffice, scrollbar

I need to access more advanced options in the sidebar in LibreOffice Writer, such as the paragraph and character options. Today, all of a sudden, these became inaccessible due to the scrollbar (see the below screenshot), even though I did nothing to change the latter (which is overlayed). I even tried undocking the sidebar, but the problem persists. I am using the default look. In the view settings, the icon size is set to automatic and the icon style is Colibre. I have tried finding a solution on Google and by looking through the settings, but in vain (Google often brings up results that have nothing to do with what I searched for). I know that I can right click to access the advanced formatting options, but that interrupts down my workflow. When can I do to rectify this issue? If possible, I don't want to deactivate the overlayed scrollbar (and somehow, this wasn't an issue before).

⁂

To summarize:

Expected behavior: to be able to click the button to access more formatting options in the sidebar

Observed behavior: sidebar hides said buttons, making it impossible to click on them.

⁂

I am using LibreOffice 7.3.7.2. on Ubuntu 22.04. I also have LO 7.5.4.2. installed as an AppImage. I opened it to see if it would be any different, but I had the same issue (though I get the impression that the same config files are used).

Please let me know if anything is missing from this question.

[Picture showing scrollbar completely obscuring buttons on sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQW2e.png)